# How to make the browsers back button work in a Formhandler multistep form

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

The question is easy enough, the solutions seems not to be:

I have a Formhandler form with 3 Steps (the form is behind a login, so there is a logged in frontend user). When I use the browsers back / forward buttons I get cache errors like:
- Cache miss in Chrome 
- Document expired in Firefox

I already tried to send different types of cache headers with no effect. Does anybody know if it is possible to solve this? Killing the browsers buttons in a multistep form is something that's going to annoy my users for sure.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I would recommend: use Powermail Plugin for multistep forms.